# Clipping/Formatting the x-axis limits in sjPlot/ggPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I am trying to make plots of fixed effects from a LMER model simillar to the models used here. https://lmudge13.github.io/sample_code/mixed_effects.html.

```
library(sjPlot) 

mod <- lme4::lmer(log(elkhorn_LAI) ~ c.urchinden + c.fishmass +c.maxD + 
                    (1|site), REML= FALSE, data= subset(me_data, LAI_nonzero ==1))

p <- sjPlot::plot_model(mod, 
                   axis.labels=c("Urchin", "Depth", "Fish"),
                   show.values=TRUE, show.p=TRUE,
                   title="Effect of Herbivores on Coral Cover")
```

Which creates

[image]

I would like to be able to clip the x-axis so that its range of the graph is -1:2 and does not have the pieces extending past those points. I also want to add a central line at x = 0.

To clip the extent of the plot I've tried using both:

```
 p + xlim (-1, 2)
```

and

```
p + scale_x_continuous(name="Estimates", limits=c(-1, 2))
```

Both of which return:

```
Scale for x is already present.
Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Too add a line at x = 0 I've tried using:

```
p + geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
```

Which doesn't change the plot.

I'm not sure if `sjPlots` is the right package to do this with or if just using the `ggplot` package would allow the plots to be more customizable.

#### Data:

```
site,spur,fish_biomass,urchin_count,urchin_den,elkhorn_LAI,PC_macro,PC_turf,PC_coral,PC_CTB,maxD,maxD_meter,depth_cat,LAI_nonzero,c.fishmass,c.urchinden,c.maxD
1,1,1994.34,4,0.1,8053.2,39,20,4,14,30,9.14,shallow,1,0.662672275,-0.296119996,-0.941602086
1,2,1523.535,30,0.75,36721,25.45454545,11.81818182,6.363636364,20,30,9.14,shallow,1,0.288763207,2.170396749,-0.941602086
1,3,413.46,30,0.75,53745,32,25,3,22,30,9.14,shallow,1,-0.592848307,2.170396749,-0.941602086
1,4,607.02,24,0.6,6689,31,14,10,19,30,9.14,shallow,1,-0.439124707,1.601200577,-0.941602086
1,5,1550.507,35,0.875,426000,12,23,34,12,30,9.14,shallow,1,0.310184125,2.644726892,-0.941602086
1,6,930.744,47,1.175,103648.5,25,19,12,21,30,9.14,shallow,1,-0.182026038,3.783119236,-0.941602086
2,1,1167.735,5,0.125,46784,20,34,10,22,40,12.19,deep,1,0.006190069,-0.201253968,0.160272696
2,2,637.623,3,0.075,7963.2,45,23,13,3,40,12.19,deep,1,-0.414820082,-0.390986025,0.160272696
2,3,3233.046,0,0,193259.25,18,29,22,14,40,12.19,deep,1,1.646441364,-0.675584111,0.160272696
2,5,687.512,1,0.025,19608.4,17,29,8,24,40,12.19,deep,1,-0.37519869,-0.580718082,0.160272696
2,6,1549.638,1,0.025,65270,31,23,15,17,40,12.19,deep,1,0.309493973,-0.580718082,0.160272696
3,1,300.429,17,0.425,13436.55,16,11,23,22,24,7.31,shallow,1,-0.682616503,0.937138376,-1.602726956
3,2,183.235,9,0.225,92235.5,23.63636364,7.272727273,20,22.72727273,24,7.31,shallow,1,-0.775690917,0.178210147,-1.602726956
3,3,435.729,13,0.325,0,26,18,20,24,24,7.31,shallow,0,-0.575162468,0.557674262,-1.602726956
3,4,379.274,12,0.3,9128.2,28,14,11,19,24,7.31,shallow,1,-0.619998518,0.462808233,-1.602726956
4,1,378.704,0,0,21368.6,41,19,13,10,35,10.67,shallow,1,-0.620451207,-0.675584111,-0.390664695
4,2,1055.283,0,0,3617.5,37,17,14,14,35,10.67,shallow,1,-0.083118292,-0.675584111,-0.390664695
4,3,1068.231,0,0,19650,44.54545455,20,20,4.545454545,35,10.67,shallow,1,-0.072835107,-0.675584111,-0.390664695
4,4,691.049,0,0,2189.6,54,14,6,9,35,10.67,shallow,1,-0.372389636,-0.675584111,-0.390664695
5,1,2059.932,0,0,0,30,13,14,15,45,13.72,deep,0,0.714764847,-0.675584111,0.711210087
5,2,832.302,0,0,0,43,20,9,11,45,13.72,deep,0,-0.260207783,-0.675584111,0.711210087
5,3,1927.144,1,0.025,7065.3,26,26,3,14,45,13.72,deep,1,0.60930582,-0.580718082,0.711210087
5,4,982.168,0,0,0,31,33,2,18,45,13.72,deep,0,-0.141185562,-0.675584111,0.711210087
6,1,513.111,0,0,0,47,19,10,4,53,16.15,deep,0,-0.513706385,-0.675584111,1.592709912
6,2,286.11,0,0,0,47,13,9,2,53,16.15,deep,0,-0.693988523,-0.675584111,1.592709912
6,3,593.168,0,0,0,62,10,3,3,53,16.15,deep,0,-0.45012584,-0.675584111,1.592709912
7,1,929.558,6,0.15,14234.05,41,23,15,3,32,9.75,shallow,1,-0.182967948,-0.106387939,-0.72122713
7,2,976.104,23,0.575,9897,30,37,2,15,32,9.75,shallow,1,-0.146001536,1.506334548,-0.72122713
7,3,1662.733,8,0.2,37344,22,33,24,10,32,9.75,shallow,1,0.399312998,0.083344118,-0.72122713
7,4,502.627,5,0.125,0,42,25,10,8,32,9.75,shallow,0,-0.522032683,-0.201253968,-0.72122713
8,1,1475.118,0,0,0,12,48,12,16,50,15.24,deep,0,0.250310864,-0.675584111,1.262147478
8,2,1939.011,0,0,0,21,33,7,20,50,15.24,deep,0,0.618730484,-0.675584111,1.262147478
8,3,2303.829,0,0,0,14,42,4,25,50,15.24,deep,0,0.908465636,-0.675584111,1.262147478
8,4,1168.356,0,0,0,20,57,7,3,50,15.24,deep,0,0.006683261,-0.675584111,1.262147478
9,1,643.765,1,0.025,0,36,35,3,8,44,13.41,deep,0,-0.409942161,-0.580718082,0.601022608
9,2,1708.074,2,0.05,36556,44,22,16,3,44,13.41,deep,1,0.43532241,-0.485852054,0.601022608
9,3,3380.41,0,0,23534.95,48,24,10,1,44,13.41,deep,1,1.763476518,-0.675584111,0.601022608
9,4,1034.796,2,0.05,160083.7,32.72727273,17.27272727,18.18181818,22.72727273,44,13.41,deep,1,-0.099388881,-0.485852054,0.601022608
9,5,1439.278,0,0,19200,43,28,10,7,44,13.41,deep,1,0.22184706,-0.675584111,0.601022608
9,6,288.153,2,0.05,0,30,24,10,12,44,13.41,deep,0,-0.692365991,-0.485852054,0.601022608
10,1,158.886,7,0.175,0,37,18,8,19,27,8.23,shallow,0,-0.795028672,-0.01152191,-1.272164521
10,2,231.219,2,0.05,0,45,15,10,16,27,8.23,shallow,0,-0.737582459,-0.485852054,-1.272164521
10,3,557.18,11,0.275,1700,42,15,10,10,27,8.23,shallow,1,-0.478707184,0.367942204,-1.272164521
10,4,562.854,15,0.375,153246.5,20,21,23,11,27,8.23,shallow,1,-0.474200944,0.747406319,-1.272164521
11,1,675.749,0,0,0,49.09090909,14.54545455,8.181818182,6.363636364,51,15.54,deep,0,-0.384540758,-0.675584111,1.372334956
11,2,926.084,0,0,0,38,21,16,7,51,15.54,deep,0,-0.185726967,-0.675584111,1.372334956
11,3,403.814,0,0,0,33,20,10,11,51,15.54,deep,0,-0.600509072,-0.675584111,1.372334956
11,4,504.364,0,0,0,33,19,16,14,51,15.54,deep,0,-0.520653173,-0.675584111,1.372334956
11,5,212.557,1,0.025,0,31,14,14,11,51,15.54,deep,0,-0.75240365,-0.580718082,1.372334956
12,1,269.588,15,0.375,17289.5,31,31,8,14,35,10.67,shallow,1,-0.707110146,0.747406319,-0.390664695
12,2,254.149,17,0.425,155412,24,26,15,20,35,10.67,shallow,1,-0.71937166,0.937138376,-0.390664695
12,3,399.036,16,0.4,79880.3,38,36,11,7,35,10.67,shallow,1,-0.604303717,0.842272348,-0.390664695
12,4,403.057,19,0.475,3722.4,17,42,6,10,35,10.67,shallow,1,-0.601110275,1.126870434,-0.390664695
```

Comment: For x-axis, you might want to turn off expansion, like so: `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 2), expand = c(0, 0))`.

Comment: @teunbrand that does not work, as OP mentioned in their question. There's an implicit `coord_flip` somewhere in `plot_model`. See my answer below. You could replace `ylim` with `scale_y_continuous` in my code.

Comment: Ugh lovely stuff. This is why I have trust issues with functions that are ggplot wrappers. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ylim` and `geom_hline`:

```r
me_data <- read.table(text= readClipboard(), 
                      header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ",") 

library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)

mod <- lmer(log(elkhorn_LAI) ~ c.urchinden + c.fishmass +c.maxD + (1|site), 
            REML= FALSE, data= subset(me_data, LAI_nonzero ==1))

p <- plot_model(mod, 
                axis.labels=c("Urchin", "Depth", "Fish"),
                show.values=TRUE, show.p=TRUE,
                title="Effect of Herbivores on Coral Cover") 

p + 
  ylim(-0.5, 1.5) + # or + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.5, 1.5))
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
#> Scale for y is already present.
#> Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>